# Is this a selective SOQL?

Tags: governorlimits, queryexception, selectivity, custom-index

```
Select Id, Field1_Id__c, Field2__c from CustomObject__c where Field1_Id__c =: STRING_CHARACTER_BLANK AND Field2__c IN: setOfIds
```

Getting the following error when a query as above is executed from a Trigger Handler.
Field1_Id__c is an External Id and hence indexed.

> Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing. Even if a field is indexed a filter might still not be selective when: 1. The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null) 2. Data skew exists whereby the number of matching rows is very large (for instance, filtering for a particular foreign key value that occurs many times)

Answer (score 4):

If STRING_CHARACTER_BLANK is null or an empty String (which translates to null in the query), then this query is not selective. Null values are not indexed in an indexed field; in other words, you're violating the first "rule" outlined in the error:

> The filter value includes null (for instance binding with a list that contains null)

Comment: Thanks much! Is there any Salesforce documentation you could point me to where I can read more about this?

Comment: @NamitaVerma [Working with Very Large SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm).